# Cloud Firestore: Get Value from collection ID if it exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to obtain the value of a collection ID from a collection in cloud firestore if it exists:

```
export const getSlugs = async () => {
  const document = await db
    .doc(constDocumentRefs.slugs)
    .collection('<collection_id>')

    
  
  return ;
};
```

but this returns me collection reference, I can check if its empty by calling: `document.get().empty` method but not sure how do I get the value of collection, in case it is not empty.

My collection looks like this:

```
{
    key1:1
    key2:2
}
```

I want to keep it like return the actual value if collection exists otherwise return -1. Someone please help!

Comment: Try adding `.get()` to the collection reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible ways:

**From the front-end:**

As Dharmaraj mentioned in his comment, you need to fetch document(s) in the collection to see if the `querySnapshot` is empty or not. If the snapshot is empty, the collection does not exist. You can limit the query to only one document to minimize cost. For that you'll use the [`limit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#limit) method. And for checking if the `QuerySnapshot` contains a doc use the [`size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot#querysnapshotsize) property.

**From a back-end:**

The [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) offer a specific method to list collections, for example [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) for the Node.js Admin SDK (and [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections) method of a `DocumentReference` for listing sub-collections). You can implement that in a Cloud Function and call it from your front-end: I wrote an [article on this approach](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166).